# Post do textarea vazio com ajax jquery e formdata

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, textarea, formdata

Tenho um formulário que utiliza Ajax pra fazer o POST no PHP e fazer a inserção no banco de dados pra pegar os dados utilizo FormData porém o textarea insere vazio no banco.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm() {
    var myForm = document.getElementById('cadastro_anuncio');
    var form = new FormData(myForm);

    var plano = $("#plano").val();
    if (plano != 1) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url('classificados/minhaconta/cadastrar_anuncio') ?>',
            data: form,
            type: 'post',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success:

                function (data) {
                    if (data == 0) {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#code").val(data)
                        $("#comprar").submit();
                    }
                }
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Segundo o artigo [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData), o id "cadastro_anuncio" deve ser o form. Dessa forma abaixo.

```
<form id="cadastro_anuncio">
    <textarea name="myFormField"></textarea>
</form>
```

Verifique também se há o atributo "name" no textarea.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XVrvQj